# Galois Action on Coherent Sheaves Exact Functor

Tags: sheaf-theory, galois-cohomology, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a non-singular, connected projective variety and $G$ be a finite automorphism group of $X$ such that the quotient $X/G$ is well defined as variety. (especially there is a well defined action of $G$ on structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{X/G}= \mathcal{O}_X^G$).

Denote by $p: X \to X/G$ the induced well defined projection morphism.

Firsly I heard that in this case $p$ is called a "Galois morphism". Why?

Now consider the exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{G} '\rightarrow \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}''\rightarrow 0$$

of coherent sheaves over $X$.

Let assume that after applying the pushforward /direct image functor $p_*$ the sequence stay exact.

My second question is if there exist and how defined if exist an induced (canonical?) action of $G$ on any "pushed forward" coheherent sheaf $p_*\mathcal{F}$

My intention is the following: If the last question has a positive answer then I can apply to the exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow p_*\mathcal{G} '\rightarrow p_*\mathcal{G} \rightarrow p_*\mathcal{G}''\rightarrow 0$$

in this case the functor $^G$ on sheaves over $X/G$ via $p_*\mathcal{F} \to (p_*\mathcal{F})^G$

Then I'm looking for criterions which garantee the exactness of this functor.

Comment: You said several times "Obviously", but some of them are not obvious at all. Is $X$ defined over $K$ ? Otherwise, what is the action of $Gal(\mathbb{C}/K)$ ? What is the action of $G$ on a coherent sheaf on $X/G$ ? Except from the subgroups {identity} and {identity, conjugation}, do you have other examples of finite subgroup of $Gal(\mathbb{C}/K)$ ? (there are none from Artin-Schreier theorem). Finally, why do you think this has to do with Hilbert 90 ?

Comment: @Roland: Yes, sorry, that was a not really sophisticated attempt to formulate the problem without explicitelly using the "Galois morphism" terminology because I'm till now quite unfamilar with it. Especially I don't see which connection the common Galois theory has with cases when the quotient $X/G$ is well defined as scheme/variery. I hope that it is now become a bit clearer.

Comment: Ok this question makes much more sense to me than your previous one. Note that the sequence after taking $p_*$ will be exact since under your hypotheses, $p$ is finite.

Comment: @Roland: I think that it boils down to the statement that for every affine $f$ morphism the direct image $f_∗$ exact. Btw do you know a good reference for the proof of it /a sketch of the proof?  I know a proof only for the case that $f$ is a closed immersion

Comment: Well, $R^ip_*F$ is the sheaf associated to $U\mapsto H^i(p^{-1}(U),F)$. If $p$ is affine, then $H^i(p ^{-1}(U),F)$ is zero. So $R^ip_*F$ is the sheaf associated to a presheaf which vanishes on a basis. This implies that $R^ip_*F$ is zero.

Comment: @Roland: So the extra input that $p_*$ exact is redundant. What I not really relized is how explicitely this induced $G$-action on $p_*\mathcal{F}$ is defined /inherited. Up to now it's defined only on local sections of structure sheaf of $X$. Is there a canonical way to define the action $^G$ over all sheaves of the shape $p_*\mathcal{F}$ over $X/G$?

Comment: Since $G$ acts on $X$, you have for each $g\in G$ a morphism $g:X\to X$, hence a morphism $F\to g_*g^*F$. Pushing forward, you have $p_*F\to p_*g_* g^* F= p_*g^*F$ since $pg=p$. Hence, a usual condition to have an induced action on $p_*F$ is that $g^*F=F$ for all $g\in G$ (in other word, the sheaf $F$ is homogeneous). This happens if $F$ is of the form $p^*F$. In particular, this happens for $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: @Roland: So it generally doesn't make any sense to apply the $^G$ "operator " to the sequence

$$0\rightarrow p_*\mathcal{G} '\rightarrow p_*\mathcal{G} \rightarrow p_*\mathcal{G}''\rightarrow 0$$ ?

Btw: here I'm not sure If I can call it a functor; if yes over what subcategory of sheaves over $X/G$? a category of sheaves of the shape $p_*F$ and satisfying $g^*F =F$ for $F$ sheaf over $X$?

Comment: On any scheme with any group, you can consider the category of (coherent/quasicoherent/$\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) sheaves equipped with an action of $G$. Then $F\mapsto F^G$ is indeed a functor. What I described in a previous comment is "the natural" action which is rather imprecise. Have you tried to look at this when $X$ is affine ?

Comment: @Roland: If we consider affine $X= Spec(R)$ then we deal with $R$-modules with "extra" $G$-action?

Comment: Yes. This is the category one wants to work with. It is an abelian category with enough injectives...